# If $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$ and $f(x)$ has non-negative valuation then $g(x)$ and $h(x)$ also have non-negative valuation

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, commutative-algebra, valuation-theory

I am stuck at the following exercise:

> Let $v$ be a valuation on $K$ and $f, g, h$ monic polynomials in $K[x]$
> with $f(x) = g(x)h(x)$. If $f \in R_v[x]$ then $g$ and $h$ are in $R_v[x]$.

My attempt thus far is: Since $f \in R_v$ we have $v(f) \ge 0$, and since $f$ is monic we have $v(f) = v(1) = 0$. Now we should probably use that both $g$ and $h$ are monic too, to probably conclude that $v(g) = v(h) = 0$, but I do not see how.

Could you help me?

Below you can find all the relevant definitions and information I know about valuations thus far:

> In lecture I learned the following definition of valuation: Let $(K,+,\cdot)$ be a field and let $(G,+)$ be a totally ordered group. A map $v: K \longrightarrow G\cup\{\infty\}$ is a valuation if the following properties hold:
>
> - $v(ab) = v(a)+v(b)$
> - $v(a+b) \ge \min\{v(a),v(b)\}$
> - $v(a) = \infty \iff a = 0$
>
> Then we proved the basic properties:
>
> 1. $v(1) = 0$
> 2. $v(a^{-1}) = -v(a)$
> 3. $v(-a) = v(a)$
> 4. $v(a - b) \ge \min\{v(a), v(b)\}$
> 5. $ \text{If }v(a) \ne v(b), \text{ then } v(a+b) = \min\{v(a), v(b)\}$
>
> Let $v$ be a valuation on a field $K$. For $f = \sum_{i=0}^n a_ix^i \in K[X]$ we
> define $v(f) = \min \{v(a_i) \mid 0 \le i \le n\}$. We see that for $f,g \in K[x]$ holds
>
> $$v(fg) = v(f) + v(g).$$
> And finally we defined $R_v := \{k \in K \mid v(k) \ge 0\}$.

Comment: This is a particular case from a more general result, where $R_v$ is an integrally closed domain and $K$ its field of fractions. Via the result from your post and a theorem that says that an integrally closed domain in the intersection of all $K$-valuation domains containing it, we get another proof for the result I mentioned.

Comment: I think it's a good idea to denote the valuation of a polynomial $f$ by $\bar v(f)$, since this can be defined on $K(x)$ (by $\bar v(f/g)=\bar v(f)-\bar v(g)$) and extends $v$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $g,h$ are monic we have $v(g)\le 0$ and $v(h)\le 0$, so $v(gh)=v(g)+v(h)\le 0$. But we know that $v(gh)=v(f)=0$, and thus $v(g)=v(h)=0$.